# setTimeout like functionality for c++

Tags: c++, class, timeout

I would love create javascript's `setTimeout` and `setInterval` like functionality for c++ (without boost). What I would like to achieve: **A base class which could call its sub-classed member variables at a repeated or after a single delay.**

I have an `update` function already and time elapsed functionality. I have also found how to pass a member function pointer to the base class and trigger that function using:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
     template <class object>
     void triggerNow(object *obj, void (object::*func)()) {
          ((obj)->*(func))();
     }

} 

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    void update() {
         triggerNow(this, &SubClass::worked)
    }
    void worked() {
         cout << "worked!";
    }
}
```

The problem I currently face is how to store `object *obj` and `void (object::*func)()` in a vector (or other container). I am only just figuring out templates...

How can I store the two templated parameters of `triggerNow` in a vector? Once I can figure this out, I can create my setTimeout and setInterval!

Comment: You can declare an `std::vector<void (object::*)()> theVector` instance variable, then have a look at how Foundation's [legendary `NSTimer` class](http://gnustep-base.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.16.1/NSTimer_8m-source.html) does the thing (though that is Objective-C, the C parts will match :)

Comment: @Ross: how hard are your timer requirements ? do you expect to be able to do something else in the mean time ? (ie, multi-threading at play...)

Comment: Timing/timer requirement are not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to store object* and object::*func in a vector you can do it like this:

```
struct Callable
{
  virtual ~Callable () {};
  virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

template <class Object>
struct TemplateCallable : public Callable
{
  typedef void (Object::*MemberFunction)();

  TemplateCallable(Object* obj, MemberFunction mem_fun)
     : _object(obj),
       _mem_fun(mem_fun)
  {}

  void operator() ()
  {
    _object->*_mem_fun();
  }

  Object* _obj;
  MemberFunction _mem_fun;
};
```

Now you can store them as Callable's in a std::vector, because the templated version is derived from Callable. If you store pointers in a std::vector<> though you need to remember to delete them at some point.

So will get something like this:

```
class TimerSomething
{
   template <class Object>
   void registerCallback (Object* obj, void (Object::*MemFun)())
   {
     _callbacks.push_back(new TemplatedCallback<Object>(obj, mem_fun));
   }

   void triggerAll ()
   {
     for (std::vector<Callable*>::iterator iter = _callbacks.begin();
          iter != _callbacks.end(); ++iter)
     {
       (**iter)();
     }
   }

   std::vector<Callable*> _callbacks;
};
```

Comment: @MatthieuM. indeed std::function or boost::function really helps. One ends up writing a lot of code when neither boost nor C++11 is available :)

Comment: Thanks will try this! Yes, boost or C++11 would help, but I am looking for a/the *vanilla* c++ solution.

Comment: `virtual void operator() = 0;` has a compile time error of `'operator()' cannot be the name of a variable or data member`, but I added (for want of a better name) `virtual void doIt()=0`. Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: @Ross that is because the call operator should actually be `virtual void operator() () = 0`, I forgot one pair of braces, will fix now.

Answer (score 2):

No comment on the timing functionality yet.

However, since you are using parent and base classes, I would suggest using polymorphism, rather than a template member function.

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
        virtual void triggerMe() = 0;

 };

class SubClass1 : public BaseClass {
    public:
        virtual void triggerMe()
        {
            //real code, do something
        }

 };

class SubClass2 : public BaseClass {
    public:
        virtual void triggerMe()
        {
            //real code, do something else
        }

 };
```

Then you can just have a `vector` of pointers to `BaseClass`:

```
vector<BaseClass*> objects;

objects.push_back(new SubClass1);
objects.push_back(new SubClass2);

for (auto it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); it++)
{
    it->triggerMe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, correct me if I am wrong, this would have little advantage over `BaseClass` having `virtual void triggerMe()=0`?